# Heroku Unable To Find XML Config File

Tags: java, spring-mvc, heroku

I uploaded a Spring application to Heroku but the application crashed with the following error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/myname/myapp/config/dao-context.xml`

The file is definitely there, and it is in GIT, and the app runs successfully locally.

Any ideas what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future visitors to this question, I overcame the problem by converting my DAO XML config file to the Java Config method, therefore Spring no longer required that XML file. This didn't directly solve the issue of being unable to find the XML file, but the added benefit is that I am now using the more modern and less verbose Java Config method.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that when you are running locally, it is picking up the file on the classpath as a regular file on the filesystem (i.e. not inside of a JAR).

On Heroku, it is probably inside of a JAR file, which means it is not a regular file, and must be read as an input stream, which might look like this:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = cl.getResourceAsStream("com/myname/myapp/config/dao-context.xml");
```

You can probably reproduce the problem locally by running the same command that's in your `Procfile`.

If this is not the case, then make sure the file exists on Heroku by running this command:

```
$ heroku run ls com/myname/myapp/config/dao-context.xml
```

Comment: Thanks. I am currently referencing that file in an annotated - `@ImportResource({"classpath:com/myname/myapp/config/dao-context.xml"})`. How would I use the ClassLoader with that?

Comment: Thank you very much - this helped me tremendously! Referring to getResourceAsStream( "resource-file.yml") allowed access to a file that was stored with  the resources folder as a/b/c/resource-file.yml.