# spring boot get file on heroku

Tags: spring, heroku, spring-boot

I've a Spring Boot project with a file on resources which is been accessed using:

```
final ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        final File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("congress.json").getFile());
```

When I run spring boot locally it finds the file an everything works as expected but when I deploy the project on Heroku I see an error:

```
2016-08-13T13:56:31.400796+00:00 app[web.1]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/app/target/nytimes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/congress.json (No such file or directory)
```

Accessing to Heroku dyno using `heroku run bash` I can see the file:

```
~ $ ls
mvnw  mvnw.cmd  pom.xml  src  target
~ $ cd target/
~/target $ ls
classes  generated-sources  generated-test-sources  maven-archiver  maven-status  mvn-dependency-list.log  nytimes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  nytimes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original  test-classes
~/target $ cd classes/
~/target/classes $ ls
application.properties  com  congress.json  senate.json
```

Why the file isn't found? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @codefinger says here: [Heroku Unable To Find XML Config File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37233069/heroku-unable-to-find-xml-config-file)

I must use `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getResource`

Comment: Here is a code snippet which works for me - `try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {String content = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));}`